# How to uninstall TexLive2020 on win10?

Tags: installing

I did several mistakes...
At first, I chose to install the medium size instead of the whole. Afterwards, I needed to use 'Ctex' but found that it wasn't installed. So I tried to uninstall TexLive and hope to install a more complete version next time.
Then I didn't get how to successfully uninstall it. I clicked the "uninst.bat" in "C:\texlive\2020\tlpkg\installer". But it seems that nothing happened. I tried to delete the whole folder, but it warned me that I have no such administator right. Quite confusing.. I'm using the administrator account of this pc... then I changed some attributes of the "temp" folder in "C:\textlive\2020". I still couldn't delete the "temp" folder.
[image]
[image]
So what should I do now???
QAQ

Comment: You might have better luck asking on the CTeX forum (at http://bbs.ctex.org/ I believe).

Comment: Why don't you simply install more packages into your existing texlive woth the texlive manager?

Comment: you can simply delete the directory but there is no need to remove it and re-install just use tlmgr install   to install whatever packages you need

Comment: @Henri Menke, The CTeX Forum has been shut down and its current replacement is `https://github.com/CTeX-org/forum`

Comment: Try running uninst.bat as an administrator.